# Javascript doesn't execute

Tags: javascript

Any reason why this javascript won't run?

```
<script>
  alert(window.screen.availHeight+"px");
  var height = window.screen.availHeight + “px”;
  document.getElementsByClassName(“col-sm-9”).style.height = height;
</script>
```

Comment: `Java` and `Javascript` are two different languages. Have you checked the browser console for errors? If not then I recommend you start there. Also `javascript` will not recognise smart quotes. On top of that, your selector `getElementsByClassName` will return a node list/collection of elements so you need to specify which one you want to target.

Comment: I am using this script in my html content, but i don't get the alert msg i have written

Comment: Do you really have curly quotes in the script, or is that a copying error?

Comment: Are you seeing the alert?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-9').style.height
```

the getElementsByClassName method returns an array. (hint: Elements not element)

You either need to select the first element:
`document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-9')[0].style.height = height`

Or iterate though the array e.g:

```
for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-9').length; i++)
{
    document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-9')[i].style.height = height;
}
```

Comment: Fix the curly quotes

Comment: That's not JavaScript `for` syntax, it looks more like C++.

Comment: Updated my answer